# Как при наведении курсора менять CSS-свойства другого элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Есть такой код:

```
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
<div>
<p>Текст</p>
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении курсора на "**текст**" менялись стили для "**заголовка**"?

Answer (score 5):

```css
div.ph_hidden_yes {
 position: relative;
 height:0;
 width: 320px;
 opacity:0;
 transition:1s;
}

div.photo_hidden:hover + div.ph_hidden_yes {
    display: block;
    height:205px;
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo_hidden">
  текст
</div>

<div class="ph_hidden_yes">
  тра ля ля
</div>
```

```css
    .section { background:#ccc; }
    .layer { background:#ddd; }
    .section:hover img { border:2px solid #333; }
    .section:hover .layer { border:2px solid #F90; }
```

```html
<div class="section">
    <img src="myImage.jpg" />
    <div class="layer">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
```

```js
var bg = document.getElementById('dad');
document.getElementById('not').addEventListener("mouseover", function(){bg.style.background = "#c00";this.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){bg.style.background = "";});
});
```

```html
<div class="daddy"><a id="dad" href="#d">need-url</a></div>
<div class="notsun"><a id="not" href="#d">url</a></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А можно также сделать без JavaScript или с помощью Php?

Comment: @Владимир , пожалуйста. Внес правки. Пользуйтесь на здоровье.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h1 id="title">Заголовок</h1>
<div>
  <p onmouseenter=" document.getElementById('title').style.color = 'red';" onmouseout=" document.getElementById('title').style.color = 'black';">Текст</p>
</div>
```